# Modeling speed of light information propagation in space combat sim

Tags: simulations

I'm working on a space combat sim that takes place over relatively vast areas (a cube of space ~20 light minutes to a side) and uses (mostly) realistic physics. One of the key elements I want to model is the propagation speed of information across the battle space -- that is, if Player A engages his main drive on one side of the battle space, there's a 20 minute delay before Player B sees it and can react to it

Even for relatively small battle spaces this is an important factor given the speeds involved. A 500m long ship doing 30kps is going to displace itself by its full length in 1/60th of a second, so even targeting an opponent just few tenths of a light second away are going to be affected by light lag.

I've not seen this done before, and I'm wondering if there are some best practices for modeling this. Right now I'm timestamping each event and marking it with a location, putting it into a queue, and then each tick checking to see if any of the objects in the game world are newly at the edge of the [light cone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone) and adding the event to their sensor queue. I will (but haven't yet) optimize it by removing any events that have already been sensed by all the objects that can possibly sense it, but still, I think this is going to get cumbersome pretty darn fast, and eat up a lot of cycles if there are hundreds of sensing objects in play (which is pretty routine).

Are there data models which would be better suited for this that I should check out?

Comment: Dunno the answer, but I'll say what a neat question!

Comment: Whoa! Games are mostly about visualization. I need to know how do you plan to visualize opponents when pixels are far too big? Simple HUD indicators? A text mode adventure game? Please enlighten me!

Comment: You say your model is physically accurate. Is that Newtonian or relativistic? That might make a big difference on such scales.

Comment: Not that it answers the question, but maybe looking at [A Slower Speed of Light](http://gamelab.mit.edu/games/a-slower-speed-of-light/) will give you some ideas.

Comment: @JonasByström - the long-distance view is pretty complex, and I'm trying to clean it up. Basically, I'm hoping it to be a probabilistic view of where the target will be in the future, based on light lag and your ship computer's estimates of the target's max delta-v. Right now it's rather less awesome than that, though :)

Comment: @MSalters - right now, Newtonian. For the most part, objects don't get going relativistic speeds -- even two missiles burning right at each other at full speed from opposite sides of the battle space end up with closing speeds of about 20% the speed of light. Enough that one could model relativistic physics and get slightly different results, but it won't be that huge of a difference. I want to explore modeling relativistic physics, though -- I think it could make for some seriously interesting gameplay.

Comment: @Constantius - downloading now. Looks awesome. :-)

Comment: @JohnBiesnecker: That seems all fine, but what about just showing the oponents? At a distance of 1/10th of your field an opponent will eclipse 1.7e-6 arcseconds... A *LOT* less than a pixel. How will you display the opponent?

Comment: @JonasByström -- then yes, indicators on the display. Though the indicators are far far larger than the actual ships, objects in the battle space are sparse enough that there is seldom any real overlap (and if there is, and it's meaningful to the player, it's almost certainly going to be happening nearby). Honestly, I'm still working it out, though.

Comment: @JohnBiesnecker: Just look out for making into a "strategy map" game, because if the only real visualization you will have is a HUD then that's essentially what you've made. Perhaps the whole time aspect will be lost on the player in that scenario? Anyway, plan accordingly and good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just brainstorming here...

Interestingly enough, network lag is your friend in this case.  As in you WANT a delay to occur for some data packets, at least if it's about drawing.  But instead of a base lag each player would normally have for all data packets impacted by just their network speed, you need to apply specific lag for each event to each player based on the light-speed delay.

Typically the server would send out updates to all clients at the same time, but what you need is for the server to calculate the "light lag" for each event (based on distance of viewer), and then not send out an update until that time.

So for every event, calculate time delay between event and each player, then queue up that event to not be sent for drawing to that player until the delay time has passed.

This doesn't address the effect of the player changing position or speed after the event occurs, but you could potentially adjust events that had been queued based on player changes.  A player begins to move closer, move event closer in time.  Player moves away, move away in time.

Doppler shift would be an interesting thing to throw into the mix, based on the movement delta between viewer and event.

Comment: I already sort of model the changing position and speeds. Despite the scale, objects in the game don't generally get going an appreciable fraction of the speed of light, so events overtake them relatively easily, but there is a check at each tick if the receiver is in the the sphere that could have seen the event, so if you're moving toward or away at a good clip it can affect this by a few ticks. Doppler would be interesting indeed, though! Something to look into. :-)

Comment: Something to be aware of, if you use this method, no one scanning the packets will be able to get information before they should.

Eve Online does something similar with cloaked ships. When any ship moves in an area all clients are notified, but when a cloaked ship moves the clients aren't told anything. Otherwise although the client doesn't show the ship, the packets would.

Answer (score 5):

The question is: how exact do you need your delayed image to be to how it actually played out? If you're looking for 100% accuracy you're going to need to save either the actions or the state of every object on the map at each tick and, as you say, replay them on a delay based on distance. If you don't care that much about pinpoint accuracy, which you rarely need in games, you can save the state at intervals and extrapolate between them when the delay catches up. You can optimize by not saving identical updates.

Alternatively, you can vectorize all movement and save a path for each object along with a start time seen from a universal observer. Then you can just calculate the expected position of an object for each observer based on the universal time counter the local time based on the path nodes it has saved. When a path node's timestamp goes behind the lightcone of all relevant objects you discard it.

Edit: The above assumes you're going to cheat on basic relativity by having an absolute observer (I assume the player). This would rob you of some of the more Interesting aspects of time dilation but modelling those would be a project in itself >_>